# Least square in two dimensions.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 &  1\\
    1 &  1\\
    \end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix}
    2 &  3\\
    3 &  2\\
    \end{pmatrix}$. Then we have to find $X \in M_{2 \times 2}$ such that $||AX - B||$ is minimized over all $X$. This looks like least square in two dimensions. I have no idea how to proceed with the problem!!

Comment: Which norm are you working with?

Comment: Depending on your definition of $|| \cdot ||$, you can rewrite $X,B$ as elements of $\Bbb{R}^4$ and $A$ as an element of $M_{4\times 4}$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos 2 norm